# Potential Energy of Interaction Between a Sphere and a Particle Formula Derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, gravity, potential-energy, interactions

A sphere of radius R has density described by *ρ*=*ρ(r)*. Derive equation for pontetial energy of interaction between the sphere and some point particle of mass *m* which is at distance *r* from the center of the sphere. Sphere and point particle is interacting according to the universal law of gravitation.

Attempt: gravitational potential generated by shpere $$  Φ=-\frac{4πGρ}r \int_0^r r'^2 \,dr'-4πGρ\int_r^R r' \,dr'$$
is this correct? If yes, how do i relate this to the particle and derive the potential energy of interaction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravitational force acting on the particle as function of radius $r$ is [[Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity)]

$$F(r) = -\frac{GmM(r)}{r^2}$$

where $M(r) = \int_0^r4\pi \rho(r')r'^2dr'$ is the mass contained within a radius $r$. Note that for $r>R$ we have $\rho(r) = 0$ and $M(r) = M(R) \equiv M$  the total mass of the whole sphere.

The potential energy is the work needed to bring the particle to $r = \infty$. This work is given by

$$V(r) = \int_r^\infty F(r')dr'$$

To evaluate it is consider the two cases seperately: 1) the particle is outside the sphere for which

$$F(r) = -\frac{GmM}{r^2}\implies V(r) = -\frac{GMm}{r}$$

and 2) the particle is inside the sphere for which

$$F(r) = -\frac{GmM}{r^2}~~~~~~~\text{for}~~~~~~r>R$$
$$F(r) = -\frac{Gm\int_0^r4\pi r'^2\rho(r')dr'}{r^2} =  -\frac{GmM r}{R^3}~~~~~~~\text{for}~~~~~~r<R$$

where the last equality only holds is we have a sphere of constant density $\rho$. In that case

$$V(r) = \int_r^R F(r')dr' + \int_R^\infty F(r')dr' =  -\int_r^R \frac{GmM r'}{R^3}dr' - \int_R^\infty \frac{GM}{r'^2}dr' ~~~~\text{for}~~~r<R$$

again the last equality only holds if $\rho(r)$ is constant (and I leave the simple evaluation of the integral to you). This expression is just the sum of the potential energy for bringing the particle from $r$ out to $R$ and from $R$ to $\infty$ as expected.

Comment: And how to solve, when density is not constant? Would be grateful if you could give me tips/explanation on that.

Comment: @MattTheoreticalPhysics In that case you need to know the $\rho(r)$ function, otherwise the best you can do for the integral above is $V(r) = \int_r^R\frac{G m \int_0^{r'}\rho(r'')4\pi r''^2dr''}{r'^2}dr'  - \frac{GMm}{R}$ for the case $r<R$. Note that for the case $r>R$ we have $V(r) = -\frac{GMm}{r}$ no matter what $\rho(r)$ is.

Comment: One last thing, shouldn't there be + sign at potential energy in case 1), since we integrate from r to infinity and double minus makes plus after we solve definite integral? Nevertheless, thank you very much!

Comment: Please comment on how you integrate to get - there, still can't figure it out by myself

Comment: @MattTheoreticalPhysics The force should come with a $-$ in front of it since its attractive so $F = -\frac{GmM}{r^2}$. This should solve the problem.